# Is there a way where you can reassign options to dropdown in ipywidgets

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I want to update the dropdown option when i update the referred list. Is there a way of doing it?

```
options_list = []

def update_options_list():
c.exexute('SQL CODES')
for ids in c:
  options_list.append(c[0])

dropdown_lable = widgets.Dropdown(options=options_list, value = None)

def button_function():
  update_options_list
  dropdown_lable.options = options_list
```

Is there a way to apply the updated options list to dropdown_lable.options?

I come across this error: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: you should check in documentation if there is any function for this `dropdown_lable.some_function`

Comment: did you check in Google `ipywidgets dropdown update options` ?  It gives me links to solutions - and you could resolve your problem few hours ago without asking Stackoverflow.

Comment: it should works `dropdown_lable.options = options_list`

Comment: you fogot `()` when you execute `update_options_list()`

Comment: if you get error message then show full error  in question. There are other useful information in message.

Comment: in this code I don't see where you could get error `'NoneType' object is not callable` so maybe you have problem in totally differen place.

Comment: but I see other mistakes - it should be `execute()` instead of `exexute()` and you shoud append `ids[0]` instead of `c[0]`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Simply

```
dropdown_lable.options = options_list
```

---

**BTW:**

Using Google `ipywidgets dropdown update options` I found it in 5 minutes.
And you had to wait 1 hour for answer on Stackoverflow. Next time first check in Google.

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working example

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

# --- functions ---

def update_options(widget):
    global options
    
    #print('widget:', widget)
    #widget.description = 'Updated !!!'
    
    options = ['A', 'B', 'C']        
    dropdown.options = options
    
# --- main ---

options = [1, 2, 3]

dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=options)

button = widgets.Button(description='Update')
button.on_click(update_options)

box = widgets.HBox([dropdown, button])

box
```

[image]

Comment: I found this on google before. I want to update the dropdown list every time another function run, but an error " 'NoneType' object is not callable " appear when I apply. I will update more detailed codes in my question.

Comment: if you found it then you should write it in question - we can't read in your mind. You could also show code. And if you get error then you should show full error in question.

Comment: I added minimal working example. Maybe this can help you.